# Strange Cached File in Super Cache

Tags: plugins

I installed super on one of my blogs recently and it has been working fine but I have noticed that it is caching this

http://www.mydomain.com/.needs-rebuild

which i believe is part of super cache what is the deal?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's a way for wp-supercache to track the state of folders and files.

Comment: so is it a normal to see cause i dont see it in any of my other blogs that I have super cache installed on, just this one